# Replace set of values in a column with NULL

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe having ~100 columns, with various types including StringType(), IntegerType(), BooleanType(), ArrayType(StringType()). Few of these columns (including boolean/array types) have junk values from data provider such as junk,NULL,default..etc. I need to replace these values with NULL , not NULL string.

```
values_to_replace = ["junk", "NULL","default"]
replacement_value = None

for column in df.columns:
    df = df.withColumn(column, when(col(column).isin(values_to_replace), replacement_value).otherwise(col(column)))
```

**Question**: Above part of replacement works fine for string type, but running into error when dealing with columns having non string datatypes such as boolean/array.
Running into below error.

Cannot resolve "(col_name1 IN (junk, NULL, default))" due to data type mismatch: Input to `in` should all be the same type, but it's ["ARRAY", "STRING", "STRING", "STRING"].;

Cannot resolve "(col_name2 IN (junk, NULL, default))" due to data type mismatch: Input to `in` should all be the same type, but it's ["BOOLEAN", "STRING", "STRING", "STRING"].;

How can we handle this replacement for all datatypes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a common logic for all data types using isin, you can convert non-string columns to string type temporarily for the replacement operation

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import when, col
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
values_to_replace = ["junk", "NULL", "default"]
replacement_value = None
for column in df.columns:
# Convert non-string columns to StringType for replacement
    df = df.withColumn(
       column,
       when(col(column).cast(StringType()).isin(values_to_replace),
       replacement_value).otherwise(
       col(column)
       )
)
# Ensure consistent NULL representation for all data types
df = df.na.fill(replacement_value)
```

Comment: thanks Daniel. I ended up doing this yesterday after few other approaches which didnt work. Do you know how to handle for other types, if we need to handle separately for non string types instead of common logic?

Comment: it depends on the type, but I would create another sithColumn + case-when statement

Comment: lets say if type is array(string), could you please provide an example? if we do another withColumn + case-when statement as above , we run into issue of data type mismatch as mentioned on post

Comment: Well I would recommend you to use the string conversion to detect null values, aling the null value to None and then cast to the type. DO NOT CAST BEFORE aligning null values, it will cause error mismatch